# Implementing likes,comment,views counter for a product

Tags: mysql, e-commerce, counter, deadlock

Im creating an e-commerce backend where in each of my product has the following counter attributes

```
- product views
- product likes
- product comments count
```

The current database columns which I have for the product database table is

```
 - id
 - likes_count
 - views_count
 - comments_count
 - category_id
 - category_parent_id
 - category_sub_parent_id
 - handling_charge
 - shipping_charge
 - meetup_address
 - is_additional_fields
 - status
 - is_deleted
 - created_at
 - updated_at
```

As seen in the following blog [Wanelo engineering blog](http://building.wanelo.com/2014/06/20/counter-cache-a-story-of-counting.html)
implementing a counter which can frequently get updated on a single row would cause row lock on innodb which if get frequently updated can cause dead lock situations in the application. But the solution for this is pretty much explained in blog which I got an idea about. But what if there are multiple counters associated with a single product which can get updated simultaneously when the app grows. How should I be designing the database table for the counters. Should I have to maintain separate tables viz

```
likes counter table

 - id     - product_id      - count

views counter table

 - id     - product_id     - count

comments counter table

 - id     - product_id     - count
```

By maintaining separate table even if a simultaneous update comes for a product (like+comment+view) it will be updated separately and reduces chance of row dead lock situations.
If its in a single table and if the updates for all of it comes simultaneously it can cause an issue.

**Question:** Is there any better way in which I could design the tables for a counter? Any suggestions please?

Comment: consider doing all inserts instead of simply incrementing one value.  that way you could report on(counting) when such traffic occurred. or perhaps group an incrementing value by day/month/etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counter in the product table for views is fine.

A separate table for likes with columns like (product_id, user_id) so each user can only like a product once. Otherwise they would be able to mash like if it was just a simple counter.

A separate table for comments with columns such as (product_id, comment_text, date.. etc)

Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have different tables where the comments and likes are mapped to user. The counter table just records the count of number of comments or views.  But should the counts be maintained separately? As it can cause problems during updates when the number of hits increases.

Comment: I guess spreading out potential row locks as much as possible can't hurt. Slightly more annoying when writing code though. Maybe you could simulate the high traffic/high amount of user input situation and check the logs to see the deadlock info.  That could help you determine if it's worth it.  Write a few loops that update your counters and sleep for random milliseconds 1-100 between counter updates and run those for a few hours.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you run any simulations?  And what were the results?

Comment: Hi @ChrisTrudeau I havent yet. I need to do a simulation test soon, got tied up with the development. Will surely post the results out here.

Comment: Great! looking forward to it

Comment: Sure Chris. Interesting topic though!

Answer (score 0):

Using background queues for buffering inserts/updates as suggested in the link you have shared is pretty standard and I was going to suggest the same.

You can recalculate multiple counters the same way as a single counter. View counts can be cached in Memcached/Redis, or you can store them in a separate table (though I'd suggest just using some analytics solution for this).

In your worker:

```rb
class ProductCountsWorker
  # ...

  def perform(product_id)
    Product.find(product_id).update_counts!
  end
end
```

And in your model:

```rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  after_create :init_views_count_buffer

  private

  def init_views_count_buffer
    reset_views_count_buffer(views_count || 0)
  end

  def views_count_cache_key
    "#{cache_key}/views_count_buffer"
  end

  def reset_views_count_buffer(value = 0)
    Rails.cache.set(views_count_cache_key, value)
  end

  # Called from controllers etc
  def increment_views_count_buffer
    Rails.cache.increment(views_count_cache_key)
  end

  def update_counts!
    transaction do
      update!(
        likes_count: likes.count,
        views_count: views_count + (Rails.cache.fetch(views_count_cache_key) || 0),
        # Or, if you have a separate views table:
        # views_count: views.count,
        comments_count: comments.count,
      )
      reset_views_count_buffer
    end
  end
end
```

Another suggestion would be splitting this view count functionality to a concern.

[Rails Low-Level Caching docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#low-level-caching)